# XCode 4 with GCC project - symbol navigator empty and symbol not found when jump to definition

Tags: xcode, gcc, indexing, symbols

I am using XCode 4. I'm trying to navigate through symbols like I used to do in SlickEdit on a windows machine.

I have a very simple GCC project. The project is laid out like this:

projectX
projectX/mod1/src
projectX/mod1/include
projectX/mod2/src
projectX/mod2/include

Source files from mod1 can include files from mod1 and mod2. Same goes for mod2 files.

In the mod1 source files, I have several #include "../../mod2/include/blabla.h" 
In the mod2 source files, I have several #include "../../mod1/include/blabla.h"

When I select a function in a source file and right-click and do "Jump to definition" it keeps saying Symbol not found.

The same project tree in Windows using SlickEdit, I can navigate through the functions with no issues.

What options in the proect settings do I need to set to tell Xcode how to navigate in my project?

Also, the symbol navigator, I have no symbols listed.

When I created the project, I first did File - New Workspace.
Then, I right-click in the window and did new project, and chose "Command Line Tool".
I then added the folder "projectX" mentioned above.

What else do I need to do? When it didn't work, I deleted the index file in the organizer, so that when I reopen the workspace it would rebuild the index, etc, but still no success.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!!